# Rails installation issue on Windows 10. Everything but Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've tried to install Ruby on Rails, 3 or 4 different times from different sources.  I seem to have everything I need except Rails.  When I type "rails --version" it says:

> "The system cannot find the path specified".

It says I have Ruby 2.2.4 and Node is 6.9.1, but no Rails.  I'm using Windows 10.  I'd really appreciate any help, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Pleas use this Link for the install Ruby on rails 
 https://richonrails.com/articles/rails-on-windows-10-via-wsl